# Hardware aceleration doesn't work (at least with mpv)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, release-juno

Playing a video with mpv (installed via apt from standard repositories) doesn't work with hardware acceleration. mpv reports:

```
VO does not support requested hardware decoder, or loading it failed.
```

vdpau reports:

`display: :0   screen: 0
GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder
Error creating VDPAU device: 1`

Corresponding packages installed:

`libnvidia-decode-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvdpau1/bionic,now 1.1.1-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mesa-vdpau-drivers/bionic-updates,now 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
vdpau-driver-all/bionic,now 1.1.1-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
vdpauinfo/bionic,now 1.0-3 amd64 [installed]`

I'm using eOS 5.0 Juno, with an NVIDIA Optimus notebook. NVIDIA drivers are installed, and the error is present whether I'm using the discreet graphics or not. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: post the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)

Comment: More info: after running **sudo** vdpauinfo, I got the response:
`display: :0   screen: 0
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error creating VDPAU device: 1`

Comment: Are you sure you have a Nvidia card? Maybe this is a new generation of Optimus laptops but it should appear when you execute that command and it didn't. Also, how did you install the Nvidia drivers? The fail proof way is to install from Appcenter

Comment: Yes I am. And VDPAU should work with Intel Graphics either. A more complete output from lspci: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 620
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out: the system is missing two packages (in my case), which are not installed by default, but available in the repos. To resolve the issue, just run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install vdpau-va-driver libvdpau-va-gl1
```